# Extract data from dataset

Tags: regex, python-3.x, machine-learning

I need to extract title from name but cannot understand how it is working . I have provided the code below :

```
combine = [traindata , testdata] 

for dataset in combine:
    dataset["title"] = dataset["Name"].str.extract(' ([A-Za-z]+)\.' , expand = False )
```

There is no error but i need to understand the working of above code

Name

```
Braund, Mr. Owen Harris

Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)

Heikkinen, Miss. Laina

Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)

Allen, Mr. William Henry

Moran, Mr. James
```

above is the name feature from csv file and in `dataset["title"]` it stores the title of each name that is mr , miss , master , etc

Comment: What is your problem ? You don't understand your code ?

Comment: Your regex is fine, see [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/TClQLS/1).

Answer (score 0):

Your code extracts the title from name using pandas.Series.str.extract function which uses regex

> [pandas.series.str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html#pandas-series-str-extract) - Extract capture groups in the regex pat as columns in a DataFrame.

`' ([A-Za-z]+)\.'` this is a regex pattern in your code which finds the part of string that is here `Name` wherever a **.** is present.

`[A-Za-z]` - this part of pattern looks for charaters between alphabetic range of a-z and A-Z

`+` it states that there can be more than one character

`\.` looks for following **.** after a part of string

> An example is provided on the link above where it extracts a part from
>   string and puts the parts in seprate columns

Answer (score -1):

I found this specific response with the link very helpful on how to use the 'str's extract method and put the strings in columns and series with changing the expand's value from True to False.